# Console encoding in Eclipse

Tags: windows, eclipse, encoding, console

```
public void turnOffSound() {
    Mixer.Info[] mixers = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    for(Mixer.Info info : mixers) {
        System.out.println(info.getName().toString());
    }
}
```

The code gave me the result below on console

```
ÁÖ »ç¿îµå µå
2D FHD LG TV(ÀÎÅÚ(R) µð½ºÇ÷¹ÀÌ 
ÁÖ »ç¿îµå ĸó µå
½ºÅ׷¹¿À ¹ͽº(Realtek High Defi
Port 2D FHD LG TV(ÀÎÅÚ(R) µð½ºÇ
Port ½ºÅ׷¹¿À ¹ͽº(Realtek Hig
```

I tried to change the encoding which were

> UTF-8, EUC-KR, ISO-8859-1, US-ASCII, UTF-16, UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE in
>   [Run configurations] -> [Common]

Common tab in run configurations:
[image: Common tab in run configurations]

And my file encoding is `UTF-8`

Preferences in Eclipse neon:
[image: Preferences in Eclipse neon]

How can I get the correct text on console?